# SQL - WHERE clause for all but 1 column For Invoices?

Tags: sql

Sorry if this is a newbie question - but I am getting a little stuck here.

tblImport -> Imports table of invoice statement

qryReport -> Builds report grouped by State on tblImport based on SUM of Invoice Amount but ONLY for State jurisdiction. HOWEVER, although I want the invoice amount for state jurisdictions only - I want the tax amount to include ANY tax pertaining to the state (regardless of jurisdiction).

Obviously my statement looks something like this:

```
SELECT tblImport.Invoice, tblImport.State, tblImport.InvoiceAmount, tblImport.JurisdictionType, tblImport.TaxAmount
FROM tblImport
WHERE tblImport.JurisdictionType = 'State'
ORDER BY State
GROUP BY State
```

So given that, I don't want the TaxAmount to be subject to the WHERE clause. What other work arounds can I do?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? I could see a CTE being useful here, but if you're not using SQL SERVER, it doesn't really help much.

Comment: Based on the `tbl` and `qry`, I'm going to assume you're using Access.

Comment: Your query doesn't make much sense.  You are grouping by state, but have no aggregation functions.  Please provide sample data and expected output to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this

```
SELECT SUM(case when tblImport.JurisdictionType = 'State' then tblImport.InvoiceAmount else 0 end) as InvoiceAmount, 
      tblImport.State, 
      SUM(tblImport.TaxAmount) as TaxAmount
FROM tblImport
ORDER BY State
GROUP BY State
```

As you're using `Group By`, you cannot display `Invoice, JurisdictionType` without aggregation. This solution will SUM only `InvoiceAmount` for `JurisdictionType = 'State'` and include ANY tax pertaining to the state (regardless of jurisdiction)

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you! Very helpful. Only change I had to make was since this was VBA - I don't think it allows for the CASE WHEN - VBA version is IIF(). Thank you! Worked liked a charm.